# How to combine tr with xargs and cut to squeeze repeats

Tags: bash, cut, tr

The top answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109835/how-do-i-use-cut-to-separate-by-multiple-whitespace) demonstrates that `cut` can be used with `tr` to cut based on repeated spaces with

```bash
< file tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 8
```

I want to get the remotes of several Git repos in a directory and am attempting to extract the remote URL fields from each with the following:

```bash
ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} remote -vv | sed -n 'p;n' | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

However, this results in (for example) the following output, where I can see that two consecutive spaces (Unicode code point 32) are retained:

```
origin    https://github.com/jik876/hifi-gan.git
upstream  https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo.git
origin    https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2.git
```

(I have also using `xargs` with `tr`)

What am I missing here?

Comment: that's a tab character after origin - you can just do
`ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} remote -vv | cut -d '^V^T' -f2`

Comment: remark: I don't like this `ls | xargs`, better use `printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0`

Comment: Use `awk {print $2}`

Comment: @MS unfortunately this gives me an error: `cut: the delimiter must be a single character`

Comment: I guess these are not spaces. Have a look at the result of the `tr` step by piping the output into `xxd`. Perhaps it helps to pipe it through `expand`, before feeding it into `tr`?

Comment: Since all of your remotes are named "origin", you could also simply do `git config remote.origin.url`

Comment: @Anil that ^V^T is a tab character i.e. use Control_V followed by Control_T

Comment: @WilliamPursell unfortunately not all are called origin - I've amended the answer to clarify this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `git remote` contains tabs instead of spaces. Use `expand` to replace them with spaces in your script:

```
ls | xargs -I{} git -C {} remote -vv | sed -n 'p;n' | expand | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Or simply directly separate fields with tabs, which is the default field separator for `awk`, as suggested by William Pursell:

```
ls | xargs -I. git -C . remote -vv | awk '{ print $2; }'
```

Comment: This answer is correct except the final command should be `cut -d ' ' -f1` to obtain the URL field as requested in the answer. Amend the answer and I will accept it as correct

Comment: Thanks @Anil , fixed the cut command to display the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than parsing the output of `ls` and `git remote -vv`. Use proper shell loop and Git remote commands:

```bash
for d in ./*/.git/..; do git -C "$d" remote get-url origin; done
```

As the remote name can be anything, one may opt to use the value from the `remote.pushdefault` config key:

```bash
for d in ./*/.git/..; do
  git -C "$d" remote get-url "$(git -C "$d" config remote.pushdefault)"
done
```

If the config entry is not available; the first remote might be used alternatively.

Either with:

```bash
for d in ./*/.git/..; do
  git -C "$d" remote get-url "$(git -C "$d" remote | head -1)"
done
```

or with:

```bash
for d in ./*/.git/..; do
  git -C "$d" remote -v | {
    read -r _ u _;
    printf %s\\n "$u"
  }
done
```

Comment: Great answer but how can we handle the case when some repos contain only a remote called `upstream` and not `origin` (I got this error when running your command)

Comment: I've amended the answer to clarify that not all remotes are called `origin`. Thanks

Comment: @Anil I just added support for arbitrary remote names.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work (having tested) as the [`remote.pushDefault` config in Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remotepushDefault) is not set by default

Comment: @Anil I added 2 more alternatives.